# Pass arg to docker build

Tags: docker, docker-build

I want to pass a variable during **build time** and start the script with this argument on run. How do I do it?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine
ARG var
# ENV var=${var} # doesn't work
CMD ["echo", "${var}"]
# ENTRYPOINT ["echo", "$var"] # doesn't work
# ENTRYPOINT "echo" "$var" # doesn't work
```

Running:

```
docker run -t $(docker build  --build-arg  var=hello -q .)
```

Produces:

```
$var
```

Comment: try using `CMD echo $var`

Comment: curious because it works fine on my machine... There are 2 differences between our Dockerfiles: `ENV var=$var` and `CMD echo $var`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Note: Unlike the shell form, the exec form does not invoke a command
>   shell. This means that normal shell processing does not happen. For
>   example, CMD [ "echo", "$HOME" ] will not do variable substitution on
>   $HOME. If you want shell processing then either use the shell form or
>   execute a shell directly, for example: CMD [ "sh", "-c", "echo $HOME"
>   ]. When using the exec form and executing a shell directly, as in the
>   case for the shell form, it is the shell that is doing the environment
>   variable expansion, not docker.

In other words a correct Dockerfile would be:

```
FROM alpine
ARG var
ENV var $var
CMD echo $var
```

In order to build it correctly, you should run:

```
docker run -t $( docker build --build-arg=var=hello -q . )
```

src: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd